# Print Duplicate Items using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to print duplicate items using LINQ.
  e.g. I want to print 1 at 10 times.
  Here 1 is a string and 10 (Dynamic Number) is the number of times I want to print this string. 
  How can I do this?

Comment: _I want to see **some existing code** to print duplicate items using LINQ..._ (what did you try so far?)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this constructor overload:

```
int count = 10;
string s = new String('1', count);
```

Comment: Remains the question what _"print 1 at 10 times"_ actually means. Also, works with chars but OP is talking about strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to use Linq, you could use [`Enumerable.Repeat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx):

```
int copies = 10;
foreach(var s in Enumerable.Repeat("1", copies))
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

But for that matter, a simple `for`-loop would work too:

```
int copies = 10;
for(int i = 0; i < copies; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("1");
}
```